# Python sympy symbols

Tags: python, sympy

When I use "x" and "z" as symbols, I have no problem with this code:

```
from sympy import *
x, z = symbols('x z')
y = -6*x**2 + 2*x*z**0.5 + 50*x - z
solve((diff(y, x), diff(y, z)))
y.subs({x: 5, z: 25})
```

But when I use "q" and "a", solve does not give me any solution.

```
q, a = symbols('q a')
y = -6*q**2 + 2*q*a**0.5 + 50*q - a
solve((diff(y, q), diff(y, a)))
y.subs({q: 5, a: 25})
```

As you can see I use "subs" to check that there is no typo in the objective function.

UPDATE: I used "Symbol" to set each variable individually, but again using "q" and "a" does not work.

```
# This works
x = Symbol('x')
z = Symbol('z')
y = -6*x**2 + 2*x*z**0.5 + 50*x - z
solve((diff(y, x), diff(y, z)))

# This does not work
q = Symbol('q')
a = Symbol('a')
y = -6*q**2 + 2*q*a**0.5 + 50*q-a
solve((diff(y, q), diff(y, a)))
```

Thank you.

Comment: there is no typo, just double checked

Comment: Very stupid idea: try to change order of symbols. `'q a'` -> `'a q'`.

Comment: This is bizarre.  I don't know the sympy module at all, but I've been playing around with this code.  I think it's the case that the code works if the first symbol is "less than" the second symbol in the parameter to `symbols()` in terms of string comparison of their names.  Does that make any sense?  `a q` works.  And check this out.  `qqq qqs` works but `qqq qqp` does not.  I've tried a bunch of other pairs as well, and whenever the first term sorts before the second term, it works.  If the opposite is true, it doesn't.  I can't find anything in the docs to explain this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!

It all depends on an alphabetic order of your variables.

If you substitute `x` for `z` and `z` for `x` in your first example it will also stop working.

Internally solve sends the expression to the function `_solve` in `sympy.solvers` which then tries to solve your equation and fails many times.

Finally as a last effort what it does is it tries to solve `-sqrt(a) + q` or `x - sqrt(z)` by picking symbols from it through an internal function `_ok_syms`, with an argument that sorts those alphabetically (even without this argument it still would, but if wrapped with `reversed` it magically makes your examples works in the exactly opposite way).

And so it does solve `x - sqrt(z)` as `x: sqrt(z)` and `-sqrt(a) + q` as `a: q**2`.

While in the first case it ends up with an easily solvable `50 - 10*sqrt(z)`, in the second case it is lost on `-12*q + 2*sqrt(q**2) + 50` as it is not able to simplify `sqrt(q**2)`.

source:
a lot of testing on:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/solvers.py

Comment: Wow!  Way cool answer man!  I had a vague idea that it would be something like this...the order of terms somehow mattering...but I'd never have gotten near an answer like yours with years of trying.  Thanks!

Comment: *"[...] as it is not able to simplify `sqrt(q**2)`."* This is a basic simplification, so could you present evidence that supports your statement? In general it would be good, if you linked the various references to internal functions/aspects to the relevant line in the source code (via `#L<line-number>`). E.g. where can I find the *"as a last effort"* part in the source file? And using a permalink ensures that the links remain valid in the future (press `Y` on your keyboard to convert the url to a permalink).

Comment: @a_guest It isn't single-valued: `sqrt(q**2) == +/-q`

Comment: @masher Not quite. The result of `sqrt(q**2)` is `q`. This is not the same as the set of solutions for `q**2` which is `{-sqrt(q**2), sqrt(q**2)} == {-q, q}`. But `sqrt(q**2)` is always `q`.