# Why does the lexicographical ordering of symbol names in sympy make a difference?

Tags: python, sympy

Consider this code:

```
from sympy import *
q, a = symbols('q a')
y = -6*q**2 + 2*q*a**0.5 + 50*q - a
print(y)
r = solve((diff(y, q), diff(y, a)))
print(r)
```

Result:

```
2*a**0.5*q - a - 6*q**2 + 50*q
[]
```

So it fails to find any solutions.  But this code find a solution:

```
from sympy import *
a, q = symbols('a q')
print(y)
y = -6*a**2 + 2*a*q**0.5 + 50*a - q
r = solve((diff(y, a), diff(y, q)))
print(r)
```

Result:

```
-6*a**2 + 2*a*q**0.5 + 50*a - q
[{a: 5.00000000000000, q: 25.0000000000000}]
```

The only difference between the two is that the roles of `a` and `q` have been swapped. Why the difference in behavior for what would reasonably be considered two functionally identical code blocks?

I played a bunch with this.  It turns out that for any substitution of symbol names in this code, whenever the name of the first symbol mentioned in `symbols('<name1> <name2>')` is lexicographically smaller than the second symbol's name, a solution is found.  Whenever the opposite is true, a solution is not found.  I've tried many combinations.  For example, `symbols('qqq qqr')` leads to a solution, but `symbols('qqq qqp')` does not.  This holds true for any two symbol names.  In one order, you get a solution. In the other, you don't.

I've searched the `sympy` documentation, and can find no mention of the constraint that symbols provided to the `symbols()` function should be in ascending sorted order.  Why this behavior?  What is going on here?

UPDATE: Per @superbrain's fine suggestion, I've had the code print `y` in each case.  It's interesting that the two results are different, probably because of lexicographical differences in how the names of the terms relate.  Aha!  There might be something here then.  But aren't the two functions equivalent, and wouldn't they have to be unless `sympy` is screwing up?

Comment: @superbrain - thanks for the suggestions.  I like both.  I've done the second, and am looking at the first, which might actually provide an answer, although I don't think so.

Comment: @superbrain - does seeing the value of `y` give you any insight into what is going on?

Comment: I don't know how SymPy works, but I could imagine that reordering to have some effect, so I thought it would be good to show that as a possible step towards an explanation.

Comment: @superbrain - Yeah.  You were right on.  That definitely points out how sympy might do something differently in the two cases because it might be working with the terms in different orders in the two cases, and that could make a difference.

Comment: Looks like Marcin at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64638237/901925 has identified the difference.  Let's do any followup on there.